# How to log Exception.data key / values with Serilog 2?

Tags: serilog

Our legacy logging framework (.NET 4.5) would iterate over Exception.data and log each one of the Exception.data key values.  It is nice for logging contextual props related to the current exception.  Is there a way to configure Serilog to log the Exception.data key values?

Serilog 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the equivalent code for Serilog:

```
public class ExceptionDataEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (logEvent.Exception == null ||
            logEvent.Exception.Data == null ||
            logEvent.Exception.Data.Count == 0) return;

        var dataDictionary = logEvent.Exception.Data
            .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
            .Where(e => e.Key is string)
            .ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Key, e => e.Value);

        var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("ExceptionData", dataDictionary, destructureObjects: true);

        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
    }
}
```

You can find a complete program with configuration in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/nblumhardt/dddaa2139bbf4b561fa7).

A more sophisticated and flexible option is to use the [Serilog.Exceptions](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions) package, which has smarts for a number of common exception types.

Comment: The gist doesn't work at all.

Comment: Works for me... if you can post your configuration in another question I might be able to spot what's going wrong.

Comment: sorry i changed the code and don't remember what was wrong. i found another solution that worked for me.